# Reshaping Numpy Arrays

Tags: reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have a climate xarray dataset with dimensions time, latitude and longitude and a temperature variable. I want to compute the Degree centality.

I converted this xarray into a numpy 3d array (say Arr), stored its shape by "ntime, nlat, nlon = Arr.shape" and then reshaped this array into a 2-D array using the code "Arr.reshape(ntime, (nlat*nlon), order="F")". Then I computed the degree centrality by creating the network and got an array for each node say "DC". Now I want to convert this numpy array "DC" into a xarray data set with dimensions latitude and longitude and for that I need to reshape this array into a 2-D array and so I used the code "DC.reshape(nlat, nlon, order="F")". So I want to know whether this reshaping of DC is correct or not and this reshaped DC is exactly corresponding to the locations or not?

Can anyone please help?